# Link disappears in a browser

Tags: html, hyperlink, firebug

Could you please help with this one:

```
<a target="_top" href="http://reversevincheck.com/?hop=asdas&price_type=&tid=asda">
<img src="http://reversevincheck.com/view/img/banners/160x600.gif">
</a>
```

When i put this link on a page it disappears!

Here is what fire bud shows:

[image]

I i think that something wrong with the image. But what?

Comment: Normally when it's greyed out in Firebug, it means `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` css properties have been set. It could be a CSS rule, or Javascript setting that value. Post your CSS and/or Javascript to figure out where exactly the issue is.

Comment: Nothing wrong with CSS or JS. Please copy this link. ans save it in *.html file on your computer. And open this file with firefox.

Comment: Sorry to report, when I copy and paste the provided code it works as expected in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Clickable `<a>` tag with the image displaying in a block type layout.

Comment: @StevenVondruska weird. I still don't see the banner. What about that random class name that firefox assigned to the image http://screencast.com/t/TAp8WH2slH8 ?

Comment: Make sure you disable any ad-blockers, or any extensions that could have an affect. The `-moz-binding` within that CSS class seems to be your problem.

Comment: OMG! THATS SOOO EMBARRASSING! I had adblock on. Please post you answer so i can accept it :) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebug, most of the time, the greyed out element means something is setting it to `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. I couldn't reproduce the issue locally.

Because the word "banner" is in your image path, and the random string of text as a class name, make sure you have all your ad-blockers turned off (or any extensions that could modify the HTML).